# No option to publish a WebJob to Azure App Service in .Net 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, azure-webjobs

I created already many Webjobs for Azure and I always did it in the same way.
In VS2022 I chose the Worker service template for C# and .Net 6.0.

If I create a new publish profile, I usually get the options to publish to "Azure Webjobs" like you can see on my picture on the left side:

[image]

However, in one of my new projects I do not see this option and see a window like on the right in my picture instead.
Usually my screen looks like this when I create projects types like a Web Api or so, but in this case I get this screen.

But my project is a normal Hosted Service like this:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostingContext, services) =>
    {
        //my stuff...
    }).Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

How can I change this behaviour and how does VS2022 decide when to give the user which options?

Answer (score 0):

- As per my observation, it depends on the project/Application which you are trying to create. Update VS and try to publish.
- I have created a Worker service Project for C# and .Net 6.0. in VS 2022 with the latest version 17.4.0.

[image]

I am able to publish the project to Azure WebJobs.
[image]

Comment: And what determines what kind of project is created? How could I now change the project type later for example?